# Pinterest Using Python Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, pinterest

I am trying to pin over 500 links at once and am trying to write a script using the mechanize module for Python.  Does anyone know the URL structure of Pinterest to add pins in this way?

Comment: Did you look at https://developers.pinterest.com/?

Comment: @samoz Yes I did, i only get a URL link to get me to a screen where you can manipulate your pin, but not to actually execute the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no public API available as of 12/8/13:

https://en.help.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I've found that, which is why I was trying to use mechanize within python to try and get the job done.  I'm very close using the pin button documentation, but the final step to have the script mock clicking "Pin it" is what I am missing.